# I can't import render after installing with pip on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, render, odoo-8

I was trying to install odoo8 in a virtual environment with python2.7 and I got an error that `render` was not installed, i installed using `pip install render`, but when i try to import render i'm getting an error that it's not installed.

```
/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/openerp/report/interface.py
File "./odoo.py", line 160, in <module> main() 
File "./odoo.py", line 156, in main import openerp 
File "~/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/openerp/__init__.py", line 81, in <module> import report
File "~/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/openerp/report/__init__.py", line 24, in <module> import interface 
File "~/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/openerp/report/interface.py", line 31, in <module> import render 
ImportError: No module named render
```

I ran `pip freeze` to check if it's installed and it was installed because i found render in the output

```
..
render==1.0.0
..
```

I don't know what else to do, am I installing it the wrong way or not importing the right module

Comment: How are you trying to import? Please add the import statement

Comment: i'm using `import render`

Comment: I don't think the render you are looking for is the same render you have installed. Check the odoo docs or post  a full log of the error

Comment: The log below         /odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/openerp/report/interface.py
 File "./odoo.py", line 160, in <module>
    main()
  File "./odoo.py", line 156, in main
    import openerp
  File "~/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/openerp/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    import report
  File "~/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/openerp/report/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    import interface
  File "~/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/openerp/report/interface.py", line 31, in <module>
    import render
ImportError: No module named render

Comment: Please check your installation of odoo and that all the required packages are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix using this script from this link https://github.com/aschenkels-ictstudio/odoo-install-scripts/blob/master/ubuntu-14-04/odoo_install.sh